# Clearing a div and children using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

Wondering what the best / good way of doing this would be in jQuery.  I have a `<div>` that contains an unordered list which is populated using code.  I'd like to put a reset button on the page so things go from this:

```
<div id="testdiv">   
   <ul id="a_list">
     <li>value 1</li>
     <li>value 2</li>   
  </ul> 
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div id = "testdiv">
  <ul id = "a_list">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Use .empty() or .html('') creatively, something like that perhaps?

Comment: Since you already know about the functions that could be used, what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) is the way to go:

```
$('#a_list').empty();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#resetButtonId").click(function(){ $("#a_list").empty() });
```

On reset button click, empty the unordered list